# Can we style the ListView generated from clicking on <select> tag in Android Webview

Tags: android, listview, webview

As a requirement I'm displaying an IFrame form inside an Android Webview, and the form has a few `<select>` controls, which when clicked will open dropdowns. Now, the dropdowns look to be Android native ListViews (verified with Android Device Monitor's layout hierarchy view)that pops out over the screen, as seem below.

[image: The ListView that pop out when clicking on a <code><select></code> control in WebView]

As you can see the texts inside are very small, and I'm wondering what can be done to style these texts, namely to make them bigger and easier to read.